# Get physical address from a way containing nodes only

Tags: python, openstreetmap, geopandas, osmnx, geopy

I'm new to geocoding stuff.

I have a list of addresses which I have to find the nearest **residential** buildings for. At first, I'm looking for basic data of these addresses using `geopy.geocoders.Nominatim` geolocator. The data I get from `Nominatim` are, among others, `display_name`, `osm_id`, `osm_type`. After that I switch to `OSMPythonTools.api.Api` to get more detailed information (e.g. number of floors, flats etc.) from `osm_query: str = fr"{osm_type}/{osm_id}"`. Then data is saved to a `pandas` dataframe. In the next step, using `osmnx`, I try to get all geometries from addresses in the 1 km perimeter (by default). Code:

```py
# Python
import os
from pprint import pprint
from collections import defaultdict

# geodata
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
from OSMPythonTools.api import Api as OSM_Api
from OSMPythonTools.nominatim import Nominatim as OSM_Nominatim
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim as geopy_Nominatim
import osmnx as ox

# # # engines
# # geopy
# https://levelup.gitconnected.com/simple-geocoding-in-python-fb28ee5272e0
geopy_geolocator: geopy_Nominatim = geopy_Nominatim(user_agent="my_app")
geopy_geocode: geopy_geolocator.geocode = geopy_geolocator.geocode

# # OSM
api_OSM: OSM_Api = OSM_Api()

# # # dane
# test addresses load
df_addresses: DataFrame = pd.read_csv("test_addresses.csv", sep = ";")

# # # gathering data
# addresses coordinates
# https://levelup.gitconnected.com/simple-geocoding-in-python-fb28ee5272e0
# "full_address" is in custom, non-OSM format
addresses_to_analyze: dict = df_addresses["full_address"].to_list()
addresses_data: dict[list] = defaultdict(list)

for i in addresses_to_analyze:
    addresses_data["full_address"].append(i)
    
    raw_geopy_geocode_response: dict = geopy_geocode(i)

    if raw_geopy_geocode_response:
        raw_geopy_geocode_response: dict = geopy_geocode(i).raw

        osm_address = raw_geopy_geocode_response.get("display_name")
        osm_id: int = raw_geopy_geocode_response.get("osm_id")
        osm_type: str = raw_geopy_geocode_response.get("osm_type")
        place_class: str = raw_geopy_geocode_response.get("class")
        place_type: str = raw_geopy_geocode_response.get("type")

        osm_query: str = fr"{osm_type}/{osm_id}"

        raw_osm_geocode_response: dict = api_OSM.query(osm_query).tags()

        building_levels: str = raw_osm_geocode_response.get("building:levels")
        building_flats: str = raw_osm_geocode_response.get("building:flats")

        addresses_data["osm_address"].append(osm_address)
        addresses_data["osm_id"].append(osm_id)
        addresses_data["osm_type"].append(osm_type)
        addresses_data["place_class"].append(place_class)
        addresses_data["place_type"].append(place_type)
        addresses_data["building_levels"].append(building_levels)
        addresses_data["building_flats"].append(building_flats)

    else:
        addresses_data["osm_address"].append(None)
        addresses_data["osm_id"].append(None)
        addresses_data["osm_type"].append(None)
        addresses_data["place_class"].append(None)
        addresses_data["place_type"].append(None)
        addresses_data["building_levels"].append(None)
        addresses_data["building_flats"].append(None)

df_osm_data = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(addresses_data)

# extracting test address
test_address = df_osm_data.loc[0, "osm_address"]

# # # osmnx - nearest (by default - 1 km) residential locations
ox_gdf = ox.geometries_from_address(
    address = test_address,
    tags = {"building": ["house", "apartments", "residential", "detached"], "place": "house", "amenity": False,
    }
)

df_gdf = pd.DataFrame(ox_gdf)
df_gdf.reset_index(inplace=True)
df_gdf.to_excel("osmnx_geometries_perimeter.xlsx")
```

The problem is that there are some entries which contain only a type of building (which meets conditions) but no address. In such cases, I have the correct element type (`way`) but when I enter `osmid` to browser search engine I receive only a set of nodes (even though highlighted polygon is correct). **Only when I right-click the polygon and select 'Show Address' I finally get the address (also a new `osmid` and `nodes` for `way`)**. What's also interesting is that `df_gdf` contains column with lists of `nodes` but any of nodes there matches the new nodes from browser.

My questions:

1. Is it possible to re-evaluate `osmid`s to get addresses? If yes - how?
2. Could `place_id` from `Nominatim` help?

**EDIT:**

> **Only when I right-click the polygon and select 'Show Address' I finally get the address (also a new `osmid` and `nodes` for `way`)**.

In these cases I'm talking about I usually get a new `node` instead of `way` after clicking 'Show Address'.

> What's also interesting is that `df_gdf` contains column with lists of `nodes` but any of nodes there matches the new nodes from browser.

Of course I mean those entries without addresses.

**EXAMPLE**:

For a one address, I got around 150 neighbouring entries. One of the entries is [this way](https://www.openstreetmap.org/way/389852088). It contains 11 `nodes`:

```
3938255237
3938255220
3938255221
3938255209
3938255217
3938255224
3938255223
3938255230
3938255236
3938255251
3938255237
```

Both script and browser indicate no address here. When I click 'Show Address' I receive a `node` [`2710576553`](https://www.openstreetmap.org/node/2710576553) with definite address. As you can notice this `node` does not appear in the list of previous `way` `nodes`.

Comment: Please provide an example osmid returned by your OSMnx code that lacks an address but you can find the address via your browser method.

Comment: @gboeing - I've updated my question. Honestly I doubt if the problem is with `osmnx` but maybe I'm not right.

Comment: The [address node](https://www.openstreetmap.org/node/2710576553) and the [building](https://www.openstreetmap.org/way/389852088) are two completely separate objects (except for their spatial relation, i.e. the address being located inside the building). I'm not familiar with osmnx or geopandas. But if you just search for buildings then you won't get this address. You have to search for buildings and addresses (or just addresses) if you want to obtain addresses. Some buildings might have address tags on their outline, some might contain the address as part of their nodes. But this one doesn't.